# Very elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that gcd(m+1,n+1)|mn-1 ,where m and n are integers.

I have already done:

(m+1)(n+1)=mn+m+n+1

Clearly gcd(m+1, n+1)|(m+1)(n+1)

And obviously gcd(m+1),(n+1)|(m+1)(n+1)

Therefore gcd(m+1),(n+1)|mn-1. QED

Can someone give me an alternate proof?

Comment: What's the difference between your "clearly" and "obviously" statements?

Comment: Your proof does not really make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${\rm mod}\ (m\!+\!1,n\!+\!1)\!:\ m\!+\!1\equiv0\equiv n\!+\!1,\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{m,n}\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{mn}-1\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})(\color{#c00}{-1})-1\equiv 0.$

Comment: Wow, such color. Much insight.

Answer (score 1):

$mn-1=(m+1)n-(n+1)$ so if $d|m+1$ and $d|n+1$ then also $d|mn-1$.

You can take $d=\gcd(m+1,n+1)$